# Handle existential variable in the head of rules

Tags: java, prolog, owl, ontology, datalog

I want to translate and query the anonymous super classes of ontology into datalog rules. For instance I have an axiom like "`Chair subclassOf (headOf some Department)`" and I have translated this axiom like this

```
Chair(x) <- headOf(x,y)
Deaprtment(y) <- headOf(x,y)
```

Because I do not want conjunction in a head like this: `headOf(x,y), Department(y) <- Chair(x)` or existential variables in the headof the rules. so I break and translate it like above.

My question is, Is there any better way to handle the existential restriction in datalog rules without having existential variables in head of rule? For reference this example is from [LUBM Ontology](http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/projects/lubm/).

Basically I wanted to read this query in prolog.
The benchmark data do not produce any instances of class Chair. Instead, each
Department individual is linked to the chair professor of that department by
property headOf. Hence this query requires realization, i.e., inference that
that professor is an instance of class Chair because he or she is the head of a
department.

`SELECT ?X, ?Y WHERE {?X rdf:type ub:Chair . ?Y rdf:type ub:Department . ?X ub:worksFor ?Y . ?Y ub:subOrganizationOf <http://www.University0.edu> }`

I do not understand how to handle the existnetial in rules so it give me the instances of chair.

Thankyou.

Comment: I do not understand your translation. Your first two rules do not reflect the OWL axiom from my point of view. I mean, `Chair(x) <- headOf(x,y)` for example, this is not what is stated in the OWL axiom. but it looks more like a domain axiom of the property `headOf` given that your rule always infers `x` being a chair which is nowhere stated in the OWL axiom. Or do I miss something here?

Comment: @UninformedUser That is what i wanted to ask that how should i translate this anonymous OWL axiom. I know this is not the exact translation and i wanted to understand what could be the right way to represent this type of axioms in datalog rules.

Comment: @UninformedUser I have added more information in question that why I need this translation. Kindly have a look.